# Logic for Enroll contacts from list in Sitecore 9.1

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-api, marketing-automation

There is a new cool feature called *Enroll contacts from list* in Sitecore 9.1:

[image]

I'm wondering where the actual logic resists (which assembly and class). I'm going to utilize this functionality by defining a Sitecore task for this procedure.

Of course, I'm familiar with [Sitecore documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/marketing-automation-operations-api.html) about Marketing Automation Operations API, but I would like to see the original solution here :) + maybe I can use some already existing method for that. So, I don't need to maintain my own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual logic for where contacts are enrolled into Automation Plans is contained in the `Sitecore.Marketing.Automation.Client.dll`.  The name space to look for `Sitecore.Marketing.Automation.Client.Controllers.AutomationPlansController.Enroll` which calls a ***private*** method.

```
BatchSeedPlanRequestResult planRequestResult = await automationPlansController.EnrollFromContactList(campaignId, enrollContactsFromListViewModel.ContactListId).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

That private method does the work of seeding the list with contacts from a list.